# Changing Color of Radial Gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How can I change the red circle created to green circle using JavaScript?

```
#redcircle {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    red, 
    red 40px,
    transparent 20px
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add your current relevant JS.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

Reset the style like this:

```
let circle = document.getElementById('redcircle');
circle.style.backgroundImage = 'radial-gradient(circle, green, green 40px, transparent 20px)';
```

---

### Option 2

Make another css style, and replace the style like this:

```
#greencircle{

background-image:
radial-gradient(
circle,
green, green 40px, transparent 20px

);
```

```js
let circle = document.getElementById('redcircle');
circle.id = 'greencircle';
```